# В датафрейме содержится информация по нескольким регионам. Давайте выделим отдельно данные по Ростовской области и Санкт-Петербургу

Tags: python

В датафрейме содержится информация по нескольким регионам. Давайте выделим отдельно данные по Ростовской области и Санкт-Петербургу.

```
df[df['admin1'] == 'Rostovskaya Oblast', 'Sankt-peterburg']
```

выдает ошибку, помогите, в чем причина???

Comment: как по твоему должен работать твой код?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. **Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей**. См. Как создать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Либо нужно писать два отдельных условия и объединять их битовым `ИЛИ` (и обязательно оба условия в скобках):

```py
df[(df['admin1'] == 'Rostovskaya Oblast') | (df['admin1'] == 'Sankt-peterburg')]
```

Либо использовать метод `isin` со списком вариантов:

```py
df[df['admin1'].isin(['Rostovskaya Oblast', 'Sankt-peterburg'])]
```